# Vue-good-table won't display "emptystate" after being populated

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a vue-good-table that initially renders the "emptystate" message before I assign values into the rows field. After I add values to the rows field, the table is re-rendered and shows the appropriate data. If I then set the rows field to an empty array, the table does not re-render as expected to display the "emptystate" message. Instead, it continues to display the data that used to be in the array.

The template code looks like this:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <vue-good-table :columns="columnData" :rows="rowData" styleClass="vgt-table"/>
    </div>
</template>
```

I have set up watches on rowData to ensure that the state is actually changing and that it does in fact have a length of 0, but despite this, the table does not re-render to display the empty state, even though it knows that rowData is an empty array.

Has anyone ever encountered this behavior before?

Comment: It's working on my demo https://jsfiddle.net/57a2a4ce/261/
Emptystate will be displayed after 3 seconds.
Do you have any errors in browser console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, this was a bug in version 2.4.4. Updating to version 2.4.7 fixed this and another external query error I was seeing.